# IE not activating Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have the following script on my page, in Chrome, it works perfectly, but IE is not getting into the `success{}` function of `Ajax`. It goes into the `Complete{}` function perfectly fine. When I tried to send the `data` variable through the `Complete{}` function, it just displays an `[object Object]` as the contents. What can I do to get this to function in IE?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var totalstrings = "";
    var totaltimes = "";
    var trendstop = "false";
    var firstrun = "true";
    var url = "newtrend.aspx";
    $('#fm1').attr('src', "http://somepage/page1/collecttrend.aspx");

    (function worker() {
        var rand;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://somepage/page1/gettrendvars.aspx',
            success: function (data) {
                if (totalstrings.length < data.length || data === "") {
                    alert("test1");
                    if (trendstop === "false") {
                        alert("test2");
                        var iframe = document.getElementById("fm1");
                        iframe.src = iframe.src;
                        totalstrings = data;
                    }
                    if (data === "") {
                        trendstop = "true";
                    } else {
                        trendstop = "false";
                    }
                }
            },
            complete: function (data) {
                setTimeout(worker, 10000);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://somepage/page1/gettimevars.aspx',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (totaltimes != data) {
                            var iframe = document.getElementById("fm1");
                            iframe.src = iframe.src;
                            totaltimes = data;
                        }
                    },
                    complete: function (data) {
                    }
                })();
            }
        });
    })();
});
```

Comment: is that a cross domain request?

Comment: Note: The `complete` callback won't be passed the response `data`. [The `jqXHR` and `textStatus` are its only arguments.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: @AnoopJoshi No, it is localized, i just have it as a long link string because i was troubleshooting it in JSFiddle.

Comment: Note: I tried deactivating the IE cache issue, with the cache: false command as well as appending my links with random numbers and neither worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work, in conjunction with Vinicius Souza's answer. Utilizing the $.get() command rather than the ajax(), and activating the timestamp to break the caching of IE.

Thanks Everyone!

```
(function worker() {
    var rand;
    $.get("http://somepage/page1/gettrendvars.aspx?timestamp=" + new Date().getTime(), {})
        .done(function (data) {
        if (totalstrings.length < data.length || data === "") {
            if (trendstop === "false") {
                var iframe = document.getElementById("fm1");
                iframe.src = iframe.src;
                totalstrings = data;
            }
            if (data === "") {
                trendstop = "true";
            } else {
                trendstop = "false";
            }
        }

        $.get("http://somepage/page1/gettimevars.aspx?timestamp=" + new Date().getTime(), {})
            .done(function (data) {
            if (totaltimes != data) {
                var iframe = document.getElementById("fm1");
                iframe.src = iframe.src;
                totaltimes = data;
            }
        });
    })
        .fail(function () {
    });
    setTimeout(worker, 1500);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a timestamp to your ajax requests, for some reason, IE caches it sometimes.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://somepage/page1/gettrendvars.aspx?timestamp='+ new Date().getTime(),
        success: function (data) {
            if (totalstrings.length < data.length || data === "") {
                alert("test1");
                if (trendstop === "false") {
                    alert("test2");
                    var iframe = document.getElementById("fm1");
                    iframe.src = iframe.src;
                    totalstrings = data;
                }
                if (data === "") {
                    trendstop = "true";
                } else {
                    trendstop = "false";
                }
            }
        },
        complete: function (data) {
            setTimeout(worker, 10000);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://somepage/page1/gettimevars.aspx?timestamp=' + new Date().getTime(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (totaltimes != data) {
                        var iframe = document.getElementById("fm1");
                        iframe.src = iframe.src;
                        totaltimes = data;
                    }
                },
                complete: function (data) {
                }
            })();
        }
    });
```

Comment: try specify the dataType in your ajax calls, also, try the .done() callback instead of complete